# Google Maps Javascript API not setting style using function(feature) element

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm having a problem getting the `setStyle` function in a Google Maps data component to work. In the below code, I am loading a GEOJSON into the map which load successfully.

Once the map has the GEOJSON data (US Counties), I determine a list of identifiers (ZIP CODES) that gets used as data while calling into an API, returning a JSON response.

Both the GEOJSON and the API return contain identical identifiers (Think SQL JOIN) and they should match to determine the color of the polygon (HTML Color code element in the API return).

The intent is for each polygon in the GEOJSON is going to be colored by the color returned from the API call.

The problem is the setStyle function.  It appears that the javascript does NOT go into the `setStyle` function to evaluate the matching.  The Control panel ignores the inside of the function, and moves along, causing all polygons to remain black.

How do I get the two to match so the color is effective?

Here's my code:

```
  // initializer
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: { lat: 49.496675, lng: -102.65625 },
  });

  let states = new google.maps.Data({map:map});
  let counties = new google.maps.Data({map:map});
  let zips = new google.maps.Data({map:map});

   //code
   zips.loadGeoJson('data/zip_codes/GEOID_' + GEOID + '.json', {}, function (features) {

      zips.forEach(function (feature) {
        ziplist.push(feature.getProperty('ZCTA5CE20'));
      });

      $.get("data/API/zipcolor.cfm?Zip=" + ziplist.toString(), function (data) {

        zips.setStyle(function (feature) {
          for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var color = 'black';
            if (feature.getProperty('ZCTA5CE20') === data[i]['ZIPCODE']) {
              color = data[i]['COLOR'];
            }
          }
          return {
            fillColor: color
          }
        });

        zips.setStyle({
          zIndex: 4,
        });

      });
```

**UPDATE #1. added example data from solution.**

example of the GEOJSON (of note, ZCTA5CE20 is the field that contains the five-digit zip code):

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "GEOID_01025",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ZCTA5CE20": "36585", "GEOID20": "36585", "CLASSFP20": "B5", "MTFCC20": "G6350", "FUNCSTAT20": "S", "ALAND20": 353436569, "AWATER20": 10517597, "INTPTLAT20": "+31.4235226", "INTPTLON20": "-088.0844556", "STATEFP": "01", "COUNTYFP": "025", "COUNTYNS": "00161538", "NAME": "Clarke", "GEOID": "01025" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -87.935193, 31.440375 ], [ -87.935366, 31.441182 ], [ -87.935366, 31.441182 ], [ -87.935193, 31.440375 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.933669, 31.43795 ], [ -87.932417, 31.437299 ], [ -87.933669, 31.43795 ], [ -87.934359, 31.438599 ], [ -87.933669, 31.43795 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.927014, 31.436329 ], [ -87.925242, 31.436352 ], [ -87.927014, 31.436329 ], [ -87.928761334129746, 31.436412166384059 ], [ -87.927014, 31.436329 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.923066, 31.436486 ], [ -87.921979, 31.436537 ], [ -87.921398308179334, 31.436272749512071 ], [ -87.921979, 31.436537 ], [ -87.923066, 31.436486 ], [ -87.925242, 31.436352 ], [ -87.923066, 31.436486 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.915043, 31.428419 ], [ -87.913823, 31.42718 ], [ -87.915043, 31.428419 ], [ -87.916281, 31.429852 ], [ -87.915043, 31.428419 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.923948, 31.404551 ], [ -87.92272, 31.404673 ], [ -87.923948, 31.404551 ], [ -87.925035, 31.404508 ], [ -87.923948, 31.404551 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.921461, 31.405142 ], [ -87.920538, 31.405871 ], [ -87.919736, 31.406946 ], [ -87.918681, 31.407763 ], [ -87.917412, 31.408296 ], [ -87.918681, 31.407763 ], [ -87.919736, 31.406946 ], [ -87.920538, 31.405871 ], [ -87.921461, 31.405142 ], [ -87.92272, 31.404673 ], [ -87.921461, 31.405142 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.907342, 31.406068 ], [ -87.905869, 31.40473 ], [ -87.905081, 31.403372 ], [ -87.905045551204381, 31.4032321113074 ], [ -87.905081, 31.403372 ], [ -87.905869, 31.40473 ], [ -87.907342, 31.406068 ], [ -87.908735, 31.406599 ], [ -87.907342, 31.406068 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.915298, 31.394758 ], [ -87.915651291675289, 31.394784676653089 ], [ -87.915298, 31.394758 ], [ -87.914736339039564, 31.39466841468731 ], [ -87.915298, 31.394758 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.922458, 31.395767 ], [ -87.922458, 31.395767 ], [ -87.921889867455278, 31.39563403280868 ], [ -87.922458, 31.395767 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.945652, 31.37629 ], [ -87.945550571655289, 31.376191856783862 ], [ -87.945652, 31.37629 ], [ -87.945956, 31.377178 ], [ -87.945956, 31.377178 ], [ -87.945652, 31.37629 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.939925, 31.375167 ], [ -87.935991, 31.376701 ], [ -87.934375, 31.377466 ], [ -87.935991, 31.376701 ], [ -87.939925, 31.375167 ], [ -87.940412, 31.374861 ], [ -87.939925, 31.375167 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.93213, 31.378551 ], [ -87.931106, 31.379029 ], [ -87.93213, 31.378551 ], [ -87.932901, 31.377982 ], [ -87.93213, 31.378551 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.929154, 31.379639 ], [ -87.927907, 31.379794 ], [ -87.927082, 31.379838 ], [ -87.927907, 31.379794 ], [ -87.929154, 31.379639 ], [ -87.93011, 31.379419 ], [ -87.929154, 31.379639 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.918497, 31.375547 ], [ -87.917821, 31.375705 ], [ -87.917388, 31.376057 ], [ -87.917821, 31.375705 ], [ -87.918497, 31.375547 ], [ -87.919219, 31.375479 ], [ -87.918497, 31.375547 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.917291, 31.376734 ], [ -87.917595529378346, 31.377609866973401 ], [ -87.917291, 31.376734 ], [ -87.917388, 31.376057 ], [ -87.917291, 31.376734 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.920151, 31.382518 ], [ -87.920968871138982, 31.384150243363997 ], [ -87.920151, 31.382518 ], [ -87.918179, 31.378624 ], [ -87.920151, 31.382518 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.921181, 31.387318 ], [ -87.920793, 31.388025 ], [ -87.920085, 31.388996 ], [ -87.920793, 31.388025 ], [ -87.921181, 31.387318 ], [ -87.921402, 31.386473 ], [ -87.921181, 31.387318 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.917653, 31.389797 ], [ -87.916547, 31.389945 ], [ -87.915741, 31.389997 ], [ -87.914831, 31.390202 ], [ -87.91393, 31.39039 ], [ -87.914831, 31.390202 ], [ -87.915741, 31.389997 ], [ -87.916547, 31.389945 ], [ -87.917653, 31.389797 ], [ -87.918638, 31.389633 ], [ -87.917653, 31.389797 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.913263, 31.39074 ], [ -87.912147, 31.390855 ], [ -87.91076, 31.390945 ], [ -87.912147, 31.390855 ], [ -87.913263, 31.39074 ], [ -87.91393, 31.39039 ], [ -87.913263, 31.39074 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.908056, 31.390197 ], [ -87.906972, 31.38983 ], [ -87.908056, 31.390197 ], [ -87.908443209596172, 31.39034344720595 ], [ -87.908056, 31.390197 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.904263, 31.388646 ], [ -87.904035189696444, 31.388553202480686 ], [ -87.904263, 31.388646 ], [ -87.905309, 31.389072 ], [ -87.904263, 31.388646 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.898003, 31.38108 ], [ -87.896785, 31.381245 ], [ -87.898003, 31.38108 ], [ -87.898588674627788, 31.381998752171214 ], [ -87.898003, 31.38108 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.895612, 31.381357 ], [ -87.894137, 31.38205 ], [ -87.895612, 31.381357 ], [ -87.896785, 31.381245 ], [ -87.895612, 31.381357 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.893179, 31.382448 ], [ -87.892314, 31.382878 ], [ -87.891438, 31.383607 ], [ -87.890693, 31.384409 ], [ -87.890192, 31.385212 ], [ -87.890693, 31.384409 ], [ -87.891438, 31.383607 ], [ -87.892314, 31.382878 ], [ -87.893179, 31.382448 ], [ -87.894137, 31.38205 ], [ -87.893179, 31.382448 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.889812, 31.385983 ], [ -87.889516, 31.386957 ], [ -87.889812, 31.385983 ], [ -87.890192, 31.385212 ], [ -87.889812, 31.385983 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.889453, 31.387931 ], [ -87.88973779828757, 31.38910980085916 ], [ -87.889453, 31.387931 ], [ -87.889516, 31.386957 ], [ -87.889453, 31.387931 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.893398, 31.393915 ], [ -87.893637, 31.394617 ], [ -87.893398, 31.393915 ], [ -87.892878, 31.393106 ], [ -87.893398, 31.393915 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.892401, 31.395988 ], [ -87.89181, 31.396082 ], [ -87.89181, 31.396082 ], [ -87.892401, 31.395988 ], [ -87.893031, 31.395629 ], [ -87.892401, 31.395988 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.891117, 31.39607 ], [ -87.889854, 31.395741 ], [ -87.889645314312077, 31.395664671382626 ], [ -87.889854, 31.395741 ], [ -87.891117, 31.39607 ], [ -87.891765109205068, 31.396081222670219 ], [ -87.891117, 31.39607 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.888761, 31.395316 ], [ -87.888739016346022, 31.395291749989937 ], [ -87.888761, 31.395316 ], [ -87.888980542561598, 31.395405864571845 ], [ -87.888761, 31.395316 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.88793, 31.394673 ], [ -87.887654, 31.393892 ], [ -87.887633452885765, 31.393832250023447 ], [ -87.887654, 31.393892 ], [ -87.88793, 31.394673 ], [ -87.888182, 31.394982 ], [ -87.88793, 31.394673 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.890733, 31.367816 ], [ -87.890652425022154, 31.367659643456602 ], [ -87.890733, 31.367816 ], [ -87.891618, 31.369711 ], [ -87.890733, 31.367816 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.906004, 31.327998 ], [ -87.906001633642489, 31.327968090792798 ], [ -87.906004, 31.327998 ], [ -87.906087, 31.329628 ], [ -87.906004, 31.327998 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.915952, 31.324065 ], [ -87.916603527239431, 31.325188499727833 ], [ -87.915952, 31.324065 ], [ -87.914355, 31.322881 ], [ -87.915952, 31.324065 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.91682, 31.328202 ], [ -87.915854, 31.329081 ], [ -87.91682, 31.328202 ], [ -87.917079, 31.326922 ], [ -87.91682, 31.328202 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.914338, 31.329744 ], [ -87.913104, 31.330289 ], [ -87.911383, 31.331685 ], [ -87.913104, 31.330289 ], [ -87.914338, 31.329744 ], [ -87.915854, 31.329081 ], [ -87.914338, 31.329744 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.910487, 31.332976 ], [ -87.910117, 31.334061 ], [ -87.910487, 31.332976 ], [ -87.911383, 31.331685 ], [ -87.910487, 31.332976 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.911449, 31.337074 ], [ -87.912495, 31.338124 ], [ -87.914326, 31.339319 ], [ -87.912495, 31.338124 ], [ -87.911449, 31.337074 ], [ -87.91054, 31.335565 ], [ -87.911449, 31.337074 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.923226, 31.334568 ], [ -87.923214616326874, 31.334508498784189 ], [ -87.923226, 31.334568 ], [ -87.923232, 31.335706 ], [ -87.923226, 31.334568 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.935894, 31.310655 ], [ -87.936941, 31.311576 ], [ -87.938214258607019, 31.312932684584453 ], [ -87.936941, 31.311576 ], [ -87.935894, 31.310655 ], [ -87.93495741964712, 31.310085752230524 ], [ -87.935894, 31.310655 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.940211, 31.314638 ], [ -87.941518992671675, 31.31494307389703 ], [ -87.940211, 31.314638 ], [ -87.93956, 31.314269 ], [ -87.940211, 31.314638 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.960757, 31.304431 ], [ -87.959702, 31.303373 ], [ -87.958421, 31.30237 ], [ -87.959702, 31.303373 ], [ -87.960757, 31.304431 ], [ -87.961874, 31.305804 ], [ -87.960757, 31.304431 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.95415, 31.300017 ], [ -87.952935, 31.299789 ], [ -87.951813, 31.299633 ], [ -87.952935, 31.299789 ], [ -87.95415, 31.300017 ], [ -87.954942, 31.300347 ], [ -87.95415, 31.300017 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.949862, 31.299164 ], [ -87.949119, 31.298569 ], [ -87.948307, 31.297537 ], [ -87.949119, 31.298569 ], [ -87.949862, 31.299164 ], [ -87.950795, 31.299463 ], [ -87.949862, 31.299164 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.946947, 31.293742 ], [ -87.946947, 31.293742 ], [ -87.947176, 31.29497 ], [ -87.946947, 31.293742 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.957383, 31.279647 ], [ -87.956892, 31.278409 ], [ -87.957383, 31.279647 ], [ -87.957384362872276, 31.279666659432653 ], [ -87.957383, 31.279647 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.954653, 31.274436 ], [ -87.953622, 31.272967 ], [ -87.953552774136369, 31.272839806458187 ], [ -87.953622, 31.272967 ], [ -87.954653, 31.274436 ], [ -87.955685, 31.275881 ], [ -87.954653, 31.274436 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.952851, 31.27079 ], [ -87.952851, 31.27079 ], [ -87.952859005367358, 31.270836248624931 ], [ -87.952851, 31.27079 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.959692, 31.267802 ], [ -87.961336, 31.268938 ], [ -87.959692, 31.267802 ], [ -87.959007236306121, 31.267567190827947 ], [ -87.959692, 31.267802 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.966344, 31.271402 ], [ -87.967439, 31.271444 ], [ -87.966344, 31.271402 ], [ -87.96578231852726, 31.271258419857553 ], [ -87.966344, 31.271402 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.982901, 31.255196 ], [ -87.981963, 31.255373 ], [ -87.982901, 31.255196 ], [ -87.983902, 31.255229 ], [ -87.982901, 31.255196 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.980657, 31.255838 ], [ -87.979423, 31.256521 ], [ -87.980657, 31.255838 ], [ -87.981963, 31.255373 ], [ -87.980657, 31.255838 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.976768, 31.258651 ], [ -87.975713, 31.259207 ], [ -87.976768, 31.258651 ], [ -87.977834, 31.257959 ], [ -87.976768, 31.258651 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.971759, 31.259616 ], [ -87.971759, 31.259616 ], [ -87.972362001046235, 31.259688318503386 ], [ -87.971759, 31.259616 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.95152, 31.24724 ], [ -87.947499, 31.246565 ], [ -87.946013, 31.245733 ], [ -87.944034, 31.244291 ], [ -87.943105, 31.243329 ], [ -87.944034, 31.244291 ], [ -87.946013, 31.245733 ], [ -87.947499, 31.246565 ], [ -87.95152, 31.24724 ], [ -87.957408, 31.247805 ], [ -87.95152, 31.24724 ] ] ], [ [ [ -87.941952, 31.241312 ], [ -87.941163, 31.239087 ], [ -87.94091, 31.238699 ], [ -87.941163, 31.239087 ], [ -87.941952, 31.241312 ], [ -87.943105, 31.243329 ], [ -87.941952, 31.241312 ] ] ] ] } }]}
```

example of the API return:

```
[{"ZIPCODE":"36585","COLOR":"#3DE170"}]
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  What is `data[i]['ZIPCODE']`?  What is the `ZCTASCE20` property of the GeoJSON? Can you provide sample GeoJSON and `data` that exhibits the issue?

Comment: ok.  I updated the solution.  The problem is that setStyle is not executing....

Comment: Can you please provide a working codesandbox or a snippet link that reproduces the issue? It's quite difficult to debug a code that is not working or without its necessary data.

Comment: you can find a working site at https://dev.offrs.com/evan/

Comment: Your code is broken e.g. ziplist is not defined, features not used as expected etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to fix this by adding a break statement after finding a match, or better, refactor the code to use the Array's find method, which will stop at the first match.

Here's your updated code:

```
zips.setStyle(function (feature) {
  var color = 'black'; // default color

  const match = data.find(item => feature.getProperty('ZCTA5CE20') === item['ZIPCODE']);
  if(match) {
    color = match['COLOR'];
  }

  return {
    fillColor: color,
    zIndex: 4,
  };
});
```

Comment: that worked brilliantly.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `setStyle` twice, the second call (to set z-index) overwrites the previous one. You're also *initializing* the color inside loop. Lots of additional refactoring is possible but you need to start with this:

```js
ziplist = [];
zips.loadGeoJson('data/zip_codes/GEOID_' + GEOID + '.json', {}, function(features) {
  // logically speaking, this block belongs here
  zips.setStyle(function(feature) {
    return {
      fillColor: 'pink'
    }
  });
  zips.forEach(function(feature) {
    ziplist.push(feature.getProperty('ZCTA5CE20'));
  });
  // the callback will then change colors
  $.get("data/API/zipcolor.cfm?Zip=" + ziplist.toString(), function(data) {
    zips.setStyle(function(feature) {
      var color = 'black';
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (feature.getProperty('ZCTA5CE20') === data[i]['ZIPCODE']) {
          color = data[i]['COLOR'];
          break;
        }
      }
      return {
        fillColor: color,
        zIndex: 4,
      }
    });
    // must be removed
    // zips.setStyle({
    //   zIndex: 4,
    // });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi @Salman...You are not wrong, but I used the other solution because the code was alot more simpler to my development style.  I did give you a thumb up.  Appreciate the effort.